# cURL and Drupal: Storing Remote Cookies Per User

Tags: php, drupal, curl

I've got a web application in Drupal that is basically acting as a proxy to a multi-page HTML form somewhere else. I am able to retrieve the page with cURL and parse it with DOMDocument, then embed the contents of the `<form>` inside a Drupal form:

```
<?php
function proxy_get_dom($url, $method = 'get', $arguments = array()) {
  // Keep a static cURL resource for speed.
  static $web = NULL;
  if (!is_resource($web)) {
    $web = curl_init();
    // Don't include any HTTP headers in the output.
    curl_setopt($web, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    // Return the result as a string instead of echoing directly.
    curl_setopt($web, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  }

  // Add any GET arguments directly to the URL.
  if ($method == 'get' && !empty($arguments)) {
    $url .= '?' . http_build_arguments($arguments, 'n', '&');
  }

  curl_setopt($web, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  // Include POST data.
  if ($method == 'post' && !empty($arguments)) {
    curl_setopt($web, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($web, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($arguments));
  }
  else {
    curl_setopt($web, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
  }

  $use_errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
  try {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML(curl_exec($web));
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    // Error handling...
    return NULL;
  }

  if (!isset($dom)) {
    // Error handling...
    return NULL;
  }

  libxml_use_internal_errors($use_errors);

  return $dom;
}

function FORM_ID($form, &$form_state) {
  // Set the initial URL if it hasn't already been set.
  if (!isset($form_state['remote_url'])) {
    $form_state['remote_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/form.faces';
  }

  // Get the DOMDocument
  $dom = proxy_get_dom($form_state['remote_url'], 'post', $_POST);
  if (!isset($dom)) {
    return $form;
  }

  // Pull out the <form> and insert it into $form['embedded'].
  $nlist = $dom->getElementsByTagName('form');
  // assert that $nlist->length == 1

  $form['embedded']['#markup'] = '';
  foreach ($nlist->item(0)->childNodes as $childnode) {
    // It would be better to use $dom->saveHTML but it does not accept the
    // $node parameter until php 5.3.6, which we are not guaranteed to be
    // using.
    $form['embedded']['#markup'] .= $dom->saveXML($childnode);
  }

  // Apply some of the attributes from the <form> element onto our <form>
  // element.
  if (isset($element->attributes)) {
    foreach ($nlist->item(0)->attributes as $attr) {
      if ($attr->nodeName == 'action') {
        $form_state['remote_action'] = $attr->nodeValue;
      }
      elseif ($attr->nodeName == 'class') {
        $form['#attributes']['class'] = explode(' ', $attr->nodeValue);
      }
      elseif ($attr->nodeName != 'method') {
        $form['#attributes'][$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
      }
    }
  }

  return $form;
}

function FORM_ID_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Use the remote_action as the remote_url, if set.
  if (isset($form_state['remote_action'])) {
    $form_state['remote_url'] = $form_state['remote_action'];
  }
  // Rebuilt the form.
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
?>
```

However, the embedded form will not move past the first step. The issue seems to be that the page behind the proxy is setting a session cookie which I am ignoring in the above code. I can store the cookies with `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, but I'm not sure where the file should be. For one thing it should definitely be a different location for each user, and it definitely should *not* be a publicly accessible location.

My question is: How do I store and send cookies from cURL per-user in Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using sessions, then use the user's session ID to name the cookie files. e.g.

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
```

would give EVERYONE the same cookie file and they'll end up sharing the same cookie. But doing

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie-' . session_id() . '.txt');
```

will produce a unique session file for every user. You will have to manually remove that file, otherwise you're going to end up with a HUGE cookie filer repository. And if you're changing session ID's (e.g. `session_regenerate_id()`, you'll "lose" the cookie file because the session ID's won't be the same anymore.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that tells me where to put that 'cookies.txt' file so that it will be safe, or alternatively how to avoid using a file altogether. For example, by using a PHP stream wrapper (if that is possible with cURL functions). Also in Drupal I can just use `$user->uid` instead of `session_id()` and then I won't have to remove any files.

Comment: curl wants files for the cookies. can't really work around that. you can't pass in a stream wrapper or other "map this to X" type - it just takes a filename. As for where to put the file - anywhere outside your document root would be fine.

Comment: "anywhere outside your document root" is not portable in PHP. I may have control over my environment but I don't want to deal with setting up that environment outside of what I can commit into version control.

Comment: securing a directory inside your document root is also not "portable" in php... PHP can only secure things that it's processing. if someone knew your naming scheme and cookie directory path, they could get at a cookie by direct url and php couldn't do anything about it, because it wouldn't ever get involved.

Comment: Some things simply cannot be represented in version control... securing a site isn't something you can stick into a .txt file and stuff that into the VC system. vc can handle code. it can't handle anything "meta" like "you must keep your cookies outside the document root".

Comment: So you see my problem and why it isn't already solved. If I could use a PHP stream, I could store the cookie file in the database. Heck, even if I couldn't, I could create the file for that request and delete it afterward with the database backing it, but only if I can have an assured directory where PHP has write permission. Or I could parse the headers manually and store the cookie in the database that way. The keys to the solution are in Drupal somewhere. I asked the question because I had a problem; please stop just telling me what that problem is.